# how do I make a static link of libraries using gcc (gtk3)

Tags: c, gcc, static-linking, gtk3

this is the gcc command to build a c-application

```
 gcc -o bs bs/src/main3.c bs/src/gui.c bs/src/calc.c -mms-bitfields - Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gtk-3.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pixman-1 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/freetype2 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15  -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 - Ic:/gtk3_32/include/glib-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/lib/glib-2.0/include -Lc:/gtk3_32/lib  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 - lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm - latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -  lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

There is flags such as

```
-Bstatic
```

but I dont know where to put it? after the -Wl flag?

I tried the answer below and it compiled but the size of the exe is the same and without the gtk-folder (deleteted it temp.) the exe could not start. So it still depends on certain dll's. I put the flag (-Bstatic) after -mm-bitfields:

```
gcc -o bs bs/src/main3.c bs/src/gui.c bs/src/calc.c -mms-bitfields -Bstatic -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gtk-3.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pixman-1 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/freetype2 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/glib-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/lib/glib-2.0/include -Lc:/gtk3_32/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Comment: Could you please add a question or something to your text?

Answer (score 1):

The `-B` flag affects any `-l` flags that follow it.  So if for example you have this:

```
gcc -o my_prog my_prog.c -llib1 -llib2 -Bstatic -llib3 -llib4
```

Then `lib1` and `lib2` are linked dynamically while `lib3` and `lib4` are linked statically.

Edit:

The -B option should immediately preceed one or more `-l` options.  So if you want to statically link everything you would do this:

```
gcc -o bs bs/src/main3.c bs/src/gui.c bs/src/calc.c -mms-bitfields -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gtk-3.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pixman-1 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/freetype2 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/glib-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/lib/glib-2.0/include -Lc:/gtk3_32/lib -Bstatic -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Edit2:

For gcc, the flag for static linking is actually `-static`, and for dynamic linking it is `-dynamic`.

Comment: I tried this but shoudln't the exefile be much heavier when linking statically? The executable is still the same size as before.

Comment: thanks for update - I tried this too but the size is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

`-Bstatic` is a linker flag, so as you suspected, it should go after the `-Wl` flag, or rather be part of it:

```
gcc -o bs bs/src/main3.c bs/src/gui.c bs/src/calc.c -mms-bitfields -Wl,-Bstatic -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gtk-3.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/pixman-1 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/freetype2 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/libpng15 -Ic:/gtk3_32/include/glib-2.0 -Ic:/gtk3_32/lib/glib-2.0/include -Lc:/gtk3_32/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Comment: thanks - tried that too but the compiler complains about not finding certain libraries such as -lcario-gobject and so on.

Comment: That probably means you don't have static versions of those libraries available.